# Clickable object animation in android

Tags: java, android

I would like to move an image from point A to point B and clickable during this movement. Not just at the start, or at the end, but throughout. Like a moving target and poke to shoot it.

I've seen posts directing people to object animator and view property animator but no examples and I just don't understand how to do this from the documentation. Could someone show a brief code snippet to do this? Preferably programmatically without XML. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Actually I've managed to figure it out. Something like this, after you create an image (img):

```
    final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = img.animate();    // The magical View
    animator.scaleX(2);         // Zoom
    animator.scaleY(2);
    animator.setDuration(8000);
    animator.x(300).y(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ObjectAnimator animator = 
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", view.getTranslationY(), offset).setDuration(300);
    animator.start();
```

In the same time you could start "translationY" animation if you want. During animation you could click on views as usual.